# Compute the ratio : $\frac{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{√2+1}xdx}{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{√2-1}xdx}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, ratio

I want to find the ratio of the following :
$$
\frac{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{√2+1}xdx}{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{√2-1}xdx}
$$

I have tried a lot but can't solve it. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: The bounds ought to be $\frac{\pi}{2}$, otherwise don't you won't anything decent. Afterwards it becomes a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445808/integral-dfrac-int-0-pi-2-sin-x-sqrt-2-1-dx-int-0-pi-2?noredirect=1) integral.

Comment: Ya thx @Zacky i dont know why latex can't render it. It should be pi not n